# Eliminar/Cambiar Mensaje al Abrir PowerShell | Windows Terminal

Tags: windows, powershell

Hace poco descargue Windows Terminal en mi PC. Configure el tema, WSL etc etc. El detalle se encuentra en que PowerShell, CMD al abrir una nueva sesion de terminal en alguno de ellos aparece un "Mensaje", ¿Existe alguna manera de Editar ese Mensaje o bien, eliminarlo completamente?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No lo puedes editar. Pero lo puedes eliminar al añadir la opción `-nologo` en la ejecución y luego añadir un perfil en la ruta de `$profile` que se ejecutará al iniciar el powershell

Comment: @Jose este comentario es una respuesta.

Comment: Es un comentario ya que opino lo que podría hacer. Si le llega a servir pongo una respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Edita el archivo de configuración de windows terminal, abre la terminal y vete a la pestaña de configuración, o puedes abrir la configuración con la combinación de tecla Ctrl+, (control más la tecla coma), una vez ahí solo agrega al final de la línea commandline -NoLogo:

```
    "list": [
  {
    // Asegurate de que sea en el apartado de powershell.exe.
    "guid": "{61c54bd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}",
    "name": "Windows PowerShell",
    "commandline": "powershell.exe -NoLogo",
    "hidden": false
  },
```